# Magento 2 : attribute not appearing in product

Tags: product-attribute, gift-card

"tax_class_id" is the attribute i am looking for in product, but i cannot find it.

I can confirm the attribute is added in "Default" attribute set
& product has also same set assigned.

Still not able to find tax class attribute
I am using "Magento ver. 2.4.1" & checking on a Gift card product

[image]

Comment: Where you can't find it? In admin product screen? Or you mean you are trying to retrieve it in block/phtml?

Comment: In admin product screen

Comment: That's unusual. Its a core attribute, in default installation it should appear directly under the Price box as a dropdown labelled "Tax Class" within website scope.

Answer (score 0):

After adding "tax_class_id" attribute into "Default" attribute set, Just run the commands

- php bin/magento indexer reindex
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have done that but did not appear attribute in admin product screen